# Change span contents javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login page and a home page (so far) and have saved username in cookie. I do not know how to change the span to write user name

The html span

```html
<span class"username" id="username"></span>
```

The username is the variable 'username'

```js
var username = document.getElementById('username-html').value
```

All I need help is the line of code to add the username into the span.

Comment: Is `username-html` your login input element?

Comment: `document.getElementById('username').innerText = username;` ?

Comment: Yes, it is an text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following HTML

```html
<span class="username" id="username"></span>
```

You can use the `innerHTML` property on the retrieved DOM node to set the username as the span contents.

```js
// let's say the username is stored in the currentUsername variable
const username = document.getElementById('username');
username.innerHTML = currentUsername;
```

There are good docs maintained by Mozilla for this and most other standard (and non-standard) DOM manipulations questions. [Here's the page for innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#reading_the_html_contents_of_an_element) and using it to set/retrieve content from an HTMLElement.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('username-html').value = username;
```

if i understood you?!